# Android lock screen bug after system files deleted

Tags: lock-screens, file-system, password, pattern-lock

I accidentally deleted some system files ( I was on `adb` connection) .

And lock screen stopped working right after.

The issue is that,
I have a lock pin/pattern/password, but system says, it's not correct password.
I changed my password with removing password files from system, and set a new password. But the error was same, `incorrect password`.
I tried to flash ROM, but it didn't help.After flashing ROM , abd and TWRP broke too, because of the password issue.
Also I can't add custom ssl certificates, because the password problem .

Samsung Galaxy s7, Android 9 with Hyper ROM (Galaxy Note port).

What should I do to repair my system files?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the /data/system folder you should delete

```
password.key
pattern.key
locksettings.db
locksettings.db-shm
locksettings.db-wal
```

all of them who existing.

Comment: I removed them to cancel lock screen, but I have to set a password for adding custom ssl certificates. So, I need that.

Comment: if you delete this files you can go to settings and set a new password

Comment: Dear friend, I already know my password. The issue about password checking mechanism.

Comment: After I set a new password, it throwing same error; incorrect password.

Comment: Did you try a dirty flash?, or if you know which files you deleted on hyper rom you can try to extract them from the flashable zip and replace them.

Comment: I tried dirty flash, it wasn't worked. I don't know the missing files. Also I have 31 gb backup on my device...

Comment: Then try something like that: make Data Backup with twrp then make a clean flash and try to restore Data Backup, if this also breaks the mechanism then try with the migrate App from XDA

Comment: can you suggest mtp hackup tool from pc? because i haven't enough space in my phone. and windows mtp file transfer also throwing error with big size folders.

Comment: you can try it with something like this `adb backup -all` or holo backup i think this can backup apps too, but no warranty.

Comment: i cant use adb too, i think it because authentication problem. I'll try holo backup

Comment: try it with this, this should solve your adb problem temporarily [how-to-solve-adb-device-unauthorized-in-android-adb-host-device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213954/how-to-solve-adb-device-unauthorized-in-android-adb-host-device/36507415#36507415)

Comment: I tried all steps twice but i'm still getting `adb: device unauthorized.`

Comment: Seems `/data/` encrypted, in twrp.